Can a type be added that references an in-memory assembly?
The following code creates an in-memory type, finds its assembly, then attempts to add another type referencing the first:
Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'namespace MyNamespace { public class c {}}'

$assembly =
  $([System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.
    GetAssemblies().
    GetTypes()                          |
    ? {$_.Namespace -eq 'MyNamespace' } |
    % Assembly                          |
    Select-Object -Unique -First 1       )

Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'namespace MyNamespace {public class d : c {}}' `
    -ReferencedAssemblies $assembly

The attempt fails with error
Add-Type: C:\repro.ps1:12
Line |
  12 |  Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'namespace MyNamespace {public class d : c { …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The value cannot be an empty string. (Parameter 'path')

which suggests Add-Type is looking for a path that probably doesn't exist since the assembly only exists in-memory.
Can a type be added that references an in-memory-only type?
What works
The following approach works but requires the assemblies to exist in the filesystem:
Remove-Item .\c.dll,.\d.dll -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Add-Type `
    -TypeDefinition 'namespace MyNamespace { public class c {}}' `
    -OutputAssembly .\c.dll
Add-Type -Path .\c.dll
[MyNamespace.c]::new()

Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'namespace MyNamespace {public class d : c {}}' `
    -ReferencedAssemblies .\c.dll `
    -OutputAssembly       .\d.dll

Add-Type -Path .\d.dll
[MyNamespace.d]::new()


No, the (C#) compiler won't have access to in-memory modules, you'll need to compile them at the same time, or rely on c.dll for storing the first one on disk (d.dll shouldn't be necessary here though)

Raw C# can do that in memory. Not sure how you would translate that to powershell though.

@JeremyLakeman If you happen to have a C# demonstration, I'm optimistic I can translate it to PowerShell.

Hmmm .... there's this hack for creating a MetadataReference from an assembly https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36590#issuecomment-689883856. Written as a workaround for when an application is published as a single executable . Not sure if there's any new support in the runtime. Then I'm sure you can find a CSharpCompilation.Create(...).Emit(...), new AssemblyLoadContext(...).LoadFromStream(...) example.

Found a relevant question and posted my version of that comment as an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79201797/4139809.

Note that if you Emit the first type, then you can probably ModuleMetadata.CreateFromImage from the assembly bytes without the unsafe code.

@JeremyLakeman I did get this working.  I opened this issue.  There is a working demonstration there.  Thank you for helping me get there.


The answer is implied by your own findings in the question, but let me spell it out:
As of PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.4.x:
Indeed, while Add-Type's -ReferencedAssemblies parameter does accept [System.Reflection.Assembly] instances (which stringify to their .FullName property in the context of binding to this [string[]]-typed parameter) (as an alternative to passing assembly file paths), such instances are only recognized if they represent an on-disk assembly, i.e. one whose .Location property reports a file-system path.
Since Add-Type -TypeDefinition calls produce in-memory assemblies in the absence of an -OutputAssembly argument, such assemblies cannot be used as -ReferencedAssemblies arguments in later Add-Type calls.

It seems that this constraint - which isn't currently documented - is imposed by PowerShell, not by the underlying .NET type implementing the C# compiler, which is called in-process from PowerShell.[1]

Therefore, it is conceivable that a future version of PowerShell 7 will lift this constraint - which hinges on someone stepping up to file an issue to that effect in the GitHub repository

Update: Commendably, you've since filed GitHub issue #24612




Thus, the solution for now is indeed to create on-disk assemblies for types that must be referenced in later Add-Type calls:
Doing so is cumbersome:

Add-Type invariably fails if the target file passed to -OutputAssembly already exists (there is no -Force switch).

While using the -PassThru switch is generally required when using -OutputAssembly in order to also load a generated on-disk assembly into the current session, it is inexplicably also needed to ensure that a later Add-Type call that uses an in-memory assembly that builds on the on-disk assembly via -ReferencedAssemblies actually surfaces the generated in-memory-assembly types in the current session.[2]

This smells like a bug: a type generated in an in-memory assembly should invariably be loaded into the current session, along with any on-disk assemblies it depends on, given that not loading an in-memory assembly into the current session is obviously pointless (it will disappear when the session exits).


On Windows, you cannot ensure that the on-disk assembly is deleted on exiting your session, because it is still locked (works fine in Unix-like environments).


if ('MyNamespace.D' -as [type]) {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Already loaded.'
}
else {

  # Note: New-TemporaryFile works in principle, but immediately *creates* the
  #       file, which would cause Add-Type to fail (it has no -Force switch)
  $tempFile = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())

  # Note: -PassThru ensures that the generated assembly is also loaded into
  #       the current session, which is seemingly a prerequisite for the 
  #       type created by the later, in-memory-assembly Add-Type call to actually
  #       surface in the current session.
  $null =
    Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -PassThru -OutputAssembly $tempFile -TypeDefinition @'
      namespace MyNamespace { public class C {} }
'@

  # Pass the file path of the generated on-disk assembly to -ReferencedAssemblies
  try {
    Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -ReferencedAssemblies $tempFile -TypeDefinition @'
    namespace MyNamespace { public class D : C {} }
'@

  }
  finally {
    Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $tempFile -Force
    if (-not $?) { # !! This invariably happens on Windows.
      Write-Warning "Failed to remove temp. assembly '$tempFile' in-session."
    }
  }
}

# Output the compiled types.
[MyNamespace.C]
[MyNamespace.D]


[1] The type that implements the C# compiler is Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation and its .Create() method's references parameter expects Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference instances, which can be obtained from in-memory assemblies, e.g. via this constructor overload.
[2] Here's a minimal repro:
$tempDll = Join-Path (Convert-Path temp:) throwaway_$PID.dll; if (Test-Path $tempDll) { Remove-Item -ErrorAction Stop $tempDll }; $null = Add-Type -OutputAssembly $tempDll -TypeDefinition 'namespace MyNamespace { public class C {} }'; Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $tempDll -TypeDefinition 'namespace MyNamespace { public class D : C {} }'; [MyNamespace.D]; Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore $tempDll || Write-Warning "Failed to delete $tempDll"
Unless you add -PassThru to the first Add-Type call - be sure to start a new session first - type [MyNamespace.D] won't be available (and neither will [MyNamespace.C]).

It seems that this constraint - which isn't currently documented - is imposed by PowerShell, not by the underlying .NET type implementing the C# compiler... Did you come across a demonstration of that .NET type referencing in-memory assemblies?  If that already works then I'm definitely inspired to open an issue in the PowerShell github repo since it would be within control of that project to implement.  It would also suggest we could experiment with this sort of thing by interacting directly with the .NET type implementing the compiler.

@alx9r, please see the footnote I've just added to the answer.

Thank you.  This has me going in the right direction, I think.

I did get this working.  I opened this issue as you suggested.  There is a working demonstration there.

Thank you, @alx9r - I've added a link to your issue to the answer.

"The answer is implied by your own findings in the question, but let me spell it out:"  BTW, please keep doing this.  I only barely understood what was happening prior to your answer here.

FYI, I've opened this documentation issue for the surprising side-effect of adding -PassThru to -OutputAssembly

"...it is inexplicably also needed to ensure that a later Add-Type call that uses an in-memory assembly that builds on the on-disk assembly via -ReferencedAssemblies actually surfaces the generated in-memory-assembly types in the current session."  I have not been able to reproduce this behavior.  Do you have a repro?

@alx9r, please see footnote [2] I've just added to the answer.

Interesting. Thank you for the repro.  I also find that behavior surprising.  I expect the second call to Add-Type to either fail or load the assembly with MyNamespace.D, but instead in that situation it does neither.
